# Election page sends us to nirvana instead of meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

The election page is suppposed to send us here to Meta, but the link is bad:

```
https://cstheory.meta.com/tags/election
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that. The link is fixed now.